# Sort by column and uniq by another column

Tags: shell, sorting, awk, uniq, solaris-10

I have below table which is divided with **";"** and it is sorted like

> Date;Name;ID;Region;Empty;CardNumber;Temperature

I needed to list max temperature of Cards which each card must be unique. Also final list must be sorted greater to smaller by temperature column.

INPUT:

```
1999;D;153;RIZE;;LT1;86
2013;D;153;RIZE;;LT2;88
2012;D;153;RIZE;;LT3;9
2011;D;153;RIZE;;LT4;81
2010;D;153;RIZE;;LT1;75
1888;D;153;RIZE;;LT2;76
2008;D;153;RIZE;;LT3;77
2006;D;153;RIZE;;LT4;78
```

OUTPUT:

```
2013;D;153;RIZE;;LT2;88
1999;D;153;RIZE;;LT1;86
2011;D;153;RIZE;;LT4;81
2008;D;153;RIZE;;LT3;77
```

I tried below command but gave an irrelevant output. Regards.

```
sort -t ';' -rnk 7 sil3 | sort -u -t ';' -rk 2,6
2011;D;153;RIZE;;LT4;81
2012;D;153;RIZE;;LT3;9
2013;D;153;RIZE;;LT2;88
2010;D;153;RIZE;;LT1;75
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GNU awk:

```
$ gawk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
                      # { k=$2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $6 }
$7>t[$6] {            # $7>t[k] {
    t[$6]=$7          #     t[k]=$7
    r[$6]=$0          #     r[k]=$0
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"
    for(i in t)
        print r[i]
}' file
2013;D;153;RIZE;;LT2;88
1999;D;153;RIZE;;LT1;86
2011;D;153;RIZE;;LT4;81
2008;D;153;RIZE;;LT3;77
```

If you don't have GNU awk available, sort output with `sort`:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
$7>t[$6] {
    t[$6]=$7
    r[$6]=$0
}
END {
    for(i in t)
        print r[i]
}' file |
sort -s -t \; -k7nr 
2013;D;153;RIZE;;LT2;88
1999;D;153;RIZE;;LT1;86
2011;D;153;RIZE;;LT4;81
2008;D;153;RIZE;;LT3;77
```

Comment: Thx, it worked, but if there is more lines which have different parameters that fails. The idea is, find unique names, and each names can have more than 1 cards, the command must be find unique cards of the name and sort as temperature.

Comment: I don't understand. Please post reflecting sample data with expected output.

Comment: If you need more parameters add them to array keys like: `t[$2 FS $6]=$7`.

Comment: The actual input will be very long, and there will be many different names, ids and regions, etc. so the parameters is unpredictible. That's why I tried "sort -u -t ';' -rk 2,6"

Comment: Put all needed parameters to the array keys. I'd imagine that this would do: `{ k=$2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $6 } $7>t[k] { t[k]=$7; r[k]=$0 }`

Comment: Wow it really worked perfect after added the line. So it is not possible to do it as only with "sort" I guess.

Comment: Well, if you reordered the temp to second column, used space delimiter (ie. used awk for both previous), `sort`ed on temp and used `uniq -f 2`, then maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may help you on same.(on a Solaris/SunOS system, change awk to /usr/xpg4/bin/awk , /usr/xpg6/bin/awk , or nawk)

```
awk -F";" '{a[$(NF-1)]=a[$(NF-1)]>$NF?a[$(NF-1)]:$NF;b[$(NF-1)]=$0;b[$(NF-1),$NF]=$0} END{for(i in a){print b[i,a[i]]}}'   Input_file
```

Comment: @Eyvz, as I mentioned if your system is Sun OS then following my post's instructions, simple `awk` will not work on it. Try `nawk` or `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk` in it?

Comment: Yes nawk worked thx, but I will have many parameters with a long input, the command does not fit for that long list.